# How to rotate a Quaternion based on angularVelocity in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to do client side prediction a rotation. I was thinking this would work is similar to how I did the position. But I can't seem to find a way to rotate my `Quaternion`.

```c#
// These are synced over the network
private Vector3 bestGuessPosition;
private Vector3 velocity;
private Quaternion bestGuessRotation;
private Vector3 angularVelocity;

// Postion
bestGuessPosition = bestGuessPosition + (velocity * Time.deltaTime);
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, bestGuessPosition, Time.deltaTime * latencySmoothingFactor);

// Rotation (not working)
bestGuessRotation = bestGuessRotation + (angularVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, bestGuessRotation, Time.deltaTime * latencySmoothingFactor);
```

How do I rotate my `bestGuessRotation`? There doesn't seem to be a `.Rotate` like there is on a `Transform`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unity two `Quaternion`s are combined using "multiplaction" [`*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) (order matters!)

You can convert your `Vector3` rotation `angularVelocity` from Euler space to a `Quaternion` using [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html)

```c#
bestGuessRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(angularVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

Btw also the position can easier be written as

```c#
bestGuessPosition += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
```

---

Just guessing you are using this in `Update` using `Lerp` might not be the best option here depending what exactly you expect from this rotation.

If using `Lerp` in `Update` for example as a simple smoothing algorithm you should remove the `Time.deltaTime` as the interpolation `factor` is a percentage value and in this case should stay the same.